Light Fixture over bathtub - How to properly remove?
There is a light fixture above the bathtub.
What is the proper way to remove the fixture so it won't be a safety hazard?
Would I need to climb up in that opening and cut the wires to the panel or wherever they are connected to? (After I turn off the breaker of course.)


A light fixture in the shower/tub space can be safe and legal - this one does not appear to have been done that way, but you don't need to remove a light  completely to get there.
Step 1 is to replace the bare-bulb-socket with a Wet Rated Fixture (NEC 410.10(A))
Step 2 is to protect the fixture (or rather, the users of the tub/shower from the fixture) with a GFCI (Ground Fault Circuit Interruptor) since it is over the tub/inside the shower. This is not directly in code, but is virtually always required by the instructions of the luminaire for over shower/tub locations, and following the instructions is in code (NEC 110.3)
If you actually want to remove it, you'll need to find the other end of the cable (presumed) or conduit (less likely) supplying it with power, and disconnect the wires there. This may be problematic if it's not a dead-end run just for this light fixture.

Where in the world are you located, as that may make a difference as to what can/should be done.  Are you wanting to remove it because of the bare bulb, or that you don't need a light in your bathtub area anymore?  It does look like there's an opening, so you should have access above.
If you just don't want a bare bulb, there are enclosed light fixtures designed for wet locations (which this would be) that could be installed in its place.  If you want to remove it, you'll need to kill power to the circuit and either remove wires back to the junction box it's fed from (likely a light switch), or at least remove any connections to this light in the junction box and cap those wires off in the junction box.  Or if this is a permanent removal, you could just cut the wires off inside the junction box they're fed from so they can't be used in the future, and consider the circuit abandoned.
Note that you can't just seal the wires above the ceiling, as any junction boxes need to be permanently accessible.

In Kentucky, US.
The fixture is in the shower space, so we were told it's not safe.
I was wondering how far back I was supposed to remove the wires to, and if I'm cutting the wires, what do I do with the end of the wires that were cut off.

I'd recommend replacing it with a proper wet-rated bathroom light fixture. They don't cost much (especially if you get the big-box-store-brand ones), and you'll probably find that at some point in the future (like when you go to sell the place) you'll want it.
